# IReport "parameter Not Found" when adding a parameter

Tags: parameters, ireport

I am using IReport 4.8.0.
I created a dataset and using it for a table and a chart and everything works fine.

Now i want to add a string parameter so the user can insert a name of city.

so i added a new string parameter inside the dataset and dragged it into Page Header.
i also updated the Dataset query so it will receive the value from the parameter:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(leads.`status`) AS Number_Of_Status,
 leads.`status` AS leads_status,
 leads.`primary_address_city` AS leads_primary_address_city
FROM
 `leads` leads
WHERE
 leads.`primary_address_city` = $P{city_to_choose}
GROUP BY
 leads.`status`
```

but all i get when pushing the "preview" is "Parameter Not Found: city_to_choose"
what did i miss?

[image]

The xml code of the report is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report44" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="94efea4a-2952-4cb2-9d88-3f853af2a264">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<style name="table">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<style name="table 1">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<style name="table 2">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<style name="table 3">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 3_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<style name="table 4">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 4_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 4_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table 4_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="281c076f-1c95-4550-aa87-5ee8f14654a6">
    <parameter name="city_to_choose" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Cupertino"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
 COUNT(leads.`status`) AS Number_Of_Status,
 leads.`status` AS leads_status,
 leads.`primary_address_city` AS leads_primary_address_city
FROM
 `leads` leads
WHERE
 leads.`primary_address_city` = $P{city_to_choose}
GROUP BY
 leads.`status`]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Number_Of_Status" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="leads_status" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="leads_primary_address_city" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Number_Of_Status">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Number_Of_Status}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
</subDataset>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select 1 as dummy_field]]>
</queryString>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="50"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="50">
        <textField pattern="">
            <reportElement uuid="ba67dc80-1d24-4900-8bae-95562947f757" x="114" y="17" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{city_to_choose}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="238" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement uuid="2692dbf7-e921-4098-a140-9ed1fc602281" key="table 4" style="table 4" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="190"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="64281428-2692-42a5-b3c0-357fd1662cb0">
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="13b614d9-0f9f-423e-8fca-4a5f2bce1dfb">
                    <jr:tableHeader style="table 4_TH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:tableFooter style="table 4_TH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 4_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="e89c0625-fb19-4b97-9bbc-80111f5d5055" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Lead Status]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="table 4_CH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 4_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="f05e13d6-93ba-42df-ab80-65f156bec0e5" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{leads_status}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="769cd50d-72b1-42f9-9c21-6c9de4a257df">
                    <jr:tableHeader style="table 4_TH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:tableFooter style="table 4_TH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 4_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="68e27cb2-6b6d-436a-8b28-a495df0a2243" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Status Count]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="table 4_CH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 4_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="6dcea81c-8d64-4e87-8c91-c958dba68005" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Number_Of_Status}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="232" splitType="Stretch">
        <pie3DChart>
            <chart>
                <reportElement uuid="0838f48f-8053-4f24-b429-74124641b223" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="232"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend/>
            </chart>
            <pieDataset>
                <dataset>
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="88beae40-88ab-4f36-9f8a-9206883f0a05"/>
                </dataset>
                <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{leads_status}]]></keyExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Number_Of_Status}]]></valueExpression>
            </pieDataset>
            <pie3DPlot>
                <plot/>
                <itemLabel/>
            </pie3DPlot>
        </pie3DChart>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: might be worth posting the XML source of your iReport as well.

Comment: i don't know... its 226 rows with a chart and a table....

Comment: You can switch to the XML view by clicking the XML button, [Highlighted Here](http://i.imgur.com/LRA72.jpg), copy the contents of that window and append it to your answer, this might aid in the resolutions.

Comment: Thank you, but as i said , it is 226 rows , so the post cuts it. it is too long.

Comment: i think the parameter is not recognized because the parameter is inside a dataset , but when i put it in the "page header" band it no longer belongs to the dataset but the master report and the master report doesn;t recognise it. but i don't know if this is true and how to override it.

Comment: thanks matthew, i solved it. The parameters from inside the dataset , need to be mapped into the master report parameters. only then the master report recognizes the parameter defined inside the dataset.

Comment: Excellent, glad you cracked it.

Answer (score 1):

This link solved the problem for me:
http://isura777.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/pass-parameters-from-main-report-to.html

The parameters from inside the dataset , need to be mapped into the master report parameters.
only then the master report recognizes the parameter defined inside the dataset.